# Integral yields log of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Assume that $f(z)$ is holomorphic and satisfies the inequality $|f(z)-1|<1$ in a region $|z|<R$. Show that $$\int_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=0$$ for all closed curves $\gamma$ in $|z|<R$. (The continuity of $f'(z)$ is taken for granted.)

The anti-derivative of $\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is just $\ln(f(z))$, which is holomorphic as long as $\ln(f(z))$ avoids the log branch cut. The log branch cut is the negative real axis, $a\leq 0$.

I want to use the **fact** that: If $f$ is the derivative of a holomorphic function in the region $\omega$, then the integral $\int_\gamma fdz$ depends only on the endpoints of $\gamma$.

To use this, we only need the condition that $f(z)$ is **not** a non-positive real number. The condition $|f(z)-1|<1$ seems like an overkill. (Of course it does imply that $f(z)$ is not a non-positive real number.) But am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Do you not know the Argument Principle? It's begging to be used...

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm using the fact which I just updated. My question is that the condition $|f(z)-1|<1$ in the problem seems unnecessarily strong. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: I believe it's just so that $f(z)$ won't have any zeros in the region :)

Comment: For $f$ to admit a logarithm on $U$ it suffices that $U$ is simply connected and $f$ is non-vanishing. I'm not sure what the non-negative real stuff is. That is a branch of the logarithm, but there are others.

Comment: @AlexYoucis If I want to use the **fact** that I posted (i.e. **not** Argument Principle), I believe I need the non-negative real stuff. Is that right?

Comment: No need to bold things friend, I can read. You're right. Since $|f(z)-1|<1$, you have that the principal branch of the logarithm is defined on $f(D_R(0))$. Thus, the rest of your argument seems fine. Also, if you didn't want to use Argument Principle, why did you accept the Argument Principle answer/

Comment: @AlexYoucis Sorry if I offended you, but it your first comments it didn't seem you noticed the fact I'm using. :) When someone posts an answer confirmed to be correct, such as here, I feel bad not to accept. Or is that actually okay?

Comment: haha, no offense taken. If you're not happy with their answer, comment and let them know why--don't accept it. That'll just get you answers you don't want. But, if you feel as though AlexM helped you, and you are now understanding everything you can keep the answer accepted :)

Comment: :) Last question, what does your symbol $D_R(0)$ mean?

Comment: It just means the disc of radius $R$ centered at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will fill in Alex Youcis's suggestion. So, By the argument principle, the integral in question is equal to $2\pi i($number of zeros - number of poles). Since $f$ is holomorphic in the region, there are no poles. So there are only zeros. By Rouche, $f(z)$ has as many zeros as the function 1, i.e. zero.

Comment: Rouche is a bit of overkill. If $|f(z)-1|<1$, then certainly $f(z)\ne 0$, else $|0-1|<1$ :) +1 though

Comment: @AlexYoucis Rouche just rolls off the tougne though

Comment: Sort of like Alex, yeah? :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis I know! We have the best name

Comment: That we do, that we do. Don't forget it.